# Loop through json-data

Tags: php, json, loops, foreach

I have a a script that generate JSON-data with this struture. Im trying to loop out this is a HTML list with PHP but now getting it right.

This is the structure of the JSON:

```
{
  "msg": [
    "msg text 1",
    "msg text 2",
    "msg text 3",
    "msg text 4",
    "msg text 5",
    "msg text 6"
  ]
}
```

My PHP code looks like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('my_json_file');
$results = json_decode($json);
$array = (array)$results;

foreach ($array as $key => $item){
        echo "Key: ".$key." Item: ".$item;
}
```

Output of this code is:

```
Key: msg Item: Array
```

Anyone who knows what i have to edit in order to get this right?

Comment: `foreach ($array['msg'] as $key => $item)` should get you what you need? Also, add `true` to your json_decode to become `$results = json_decode($json, true);` and it'll be parsed as an array rather than object

Comment: Your code works correct. It will show `msg` as an array. You must provide expected output in order to correct your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do the foreach on `array['msg']` to get all the msg items. otherwise you will loop over all the properties of the main array (in this case there is only `msg`)

```
$json = file_get_contents('my_json_file');
$results = json_decode($json);
$array = (array)$results;

foreach ($array['msg'] as $item){
        echo "Key: msg Item: ".$item;
}
```

The output will be :

```
Key: msg Item: msg text 1 
Key: msg Item: msg text 2
...
```

---

If you still want to loop over the main array and want to print the content of `msg`, you have to use print_r to print the content of the array

```
$json = file_get_contents('my_json_file');
$results = json_decode($json);
$array = (array)$results;

foreach ($array as $key => $item){
    echo "Key: ".$key." Item: ".print_r($item, true);
}
```

The output will be :

```
Key: msg Item: array [
    "msg text 1",
    "msg text 2",
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

use this example code.

```
    $json = '{
        "msg": [
        "msg text 1",
        "msg text 2",
        "msg text 3",
        "msg text 4",
        "msg text 5",
        "msg text 6"
    ]}';

    $results = json_decode($json);
    $array = $results->msg;
    foreach ($array as $key => $item){
        echo "Key: ".$key." Item: ".$item;
    }
```